# Mysql query. Update, multiply, join and select (?) all put together

Tags: mysql, select, join, operators

I am having trouble writing a sql query and I was hoping that someone may be able to help me out. 
Here's what I want my query to do:

1. Take the "prod_value" column from the "product" table
2. Multiply a constant (assume the number 2) times the "worth" column on the "value" table that corresponds to the one-to-one relationship between value <-> product.
3. Update the "prod_value" column in the "product" table to the new updated value.

For example...
Here's the tables:
value

```
  id     |      worth       |     product_id     |
   1     |         10       |         1          |
```

product (before)

```
   id    |     name        |        prod_value    |
   1     |    product1     |           100        |
```

and assume constant = 2.

Then what I want after I run the query is the following:

product (after)

```
   id    |     name        |        prod_value    |
   1     |    product1     |           120        |
```

The 120 comes from 100 (previous value) + 2*10

I was hoping to have this done with one single query, is this even possible? 
If anyone can help me I would be very grateful!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `product`
INNER JOIN `value` ON `product`.`id`= `value`.`product_id`
SET `product`.`prod_value` = `product`.`prod_value` + 2* `value`.`worth`
```

Comment: mmmm, Im assuming you wanted:

UPDATE `product`
INNER JOIN `value` ON `product`.`id`= `value`.`product_id`
SET `product`.`prod_value` = `product`.`prod_value` + 2* `value`.`worth`

but it didn't work. Is there supposed to be a set somewhere?

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I edited my post to correct the typo. What was the error message? Do you have the necessary indices to make the joined view writable?

Comment: "Do you have the necessary indices to make the joined view writable?" thats a very good question, I'll look into this. I'm no database expert, so I'll need to work into it. 

Im getting a near "INNER": syntax error. Similar to the one in the following page:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=161676

Comment: I tried my SQL statement, and no syntax error was found. Try it on one line!

Comment: Thanks for your patience, the mistake was on my side. Your answer worked!